# jQuery // Moving up and down on Arrow Down event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replicate the same event you can do inside ms access datagrid where you can use the arrow up and down to move from a row.  As for a example I only showed 2 rows but it could be much more.

I've got the following HTML

```
<div class="cell celldata cell_service_data" id="cell_service_rate_1">
<input type="text" id="rate_service_row_1" class="rate_service_row"/>
</div>
<div class="cell celldata cell_service_data" id="cell_service_rate_2">
    <input type="text" id="rate_service_row_2" class="rate_service_row"/>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('.rate_service_row').keydown(function (e) {
    var rateId = $(this).attr('id');

  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
      arrow = {left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

  switch (keyCode) {
    case arrow.left:
      //..
    break;
    case arrow.up:
      //..
    break;
    case arrow.right:
      //..
    break;
    case arrow.down:
         //Set focus to the same cell next row
    break;
  }
});
```

So my question is how can I in jquery put inside the arrow.down case the following logic.
nextcell = cell_service_rate_1 + 1 and should equal cell_service_rate_2

Comment: Can you post a 4x4 square? I'd like to see a bit more regarding how the hierarchy is composed. (Even better, make a jsfiddle.net of the grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly can't you just do like `i = 1`... `nextcell = "cell_service_rate" + i;`

EDIT
Using parseInt() this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/byjmF/3/) works doing what I think you want. I still think it's more elegant to have from the start some i counter to create the strings though.

http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/byjmF/3/

EDIT

And [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/byjmF/9/) is an example of more what I think you should be doing, by having an index (in this case the 'rel' attribute)

http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/byjmF/9/

Comment: btw if you want to add left and right.. here is what i did http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/byjmF/10/

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this?

```
var rateId = $(this).attr('id');
//Get the number of the currently selected cell
var curCell = rateId.substr(-1);

... code ...
case arrow.down:
     //Go one row lower.. so plus 1
     var newCell = curCell + 1;
     //Define the new identifier
     var newCellId = 'rate_service_row_' + newCell;
     var element = $(newCellId);
     //Focus on the element if it exists (element.length checks that)
     if (element.length != 0) {
          element.focus();
     }
break;
```

Better would be to detect the last occurence of the underscore of your rateId, rather than doing a substr(-1) because this just works for 0-9. But I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: yeah good point for 0-9.  I will add the following: var startAt= rateId.indexOf("_"); var id = rateId.slice(startAt+1, rateId.length)